# Python + SQLAlchemy + Oracle + sequences = unable to insert new row

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

**First, some background and problem description:**

I have to work with Oracle DB and need to cover it with DBAL (SQLAlchemy). My local development DB that is used for BDD/CI etc. uses MySQL hence the need for DBAL. Everything is develop in Python.

Connecting, reading operations are not a problem however I cannot Insert anything due to more than likely two problems: sequence and dates.
Just to clarify my requirements:

- Sequence: is a string field and is prefixed e.g. "ABC123". In the database it's solved by just setting `'ABC'||TEST_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL` as default. That works on the DB level. I have no idea how to make it work and use string prefix.
- Dates: as MySQL is happy with just string (e.g. `2019-01-01 12:02:03`) Oracle is obviously temperamental. I have used datetime object however that generates sql with `datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 12, 2, 3)` as date value which is not a valid SQL for Oracle, unless SQLAlchemy does some magic before executing it in the DB.

Bottom line is, I need a DBAL config that works both with Oracle and MySQL that uses string prefix sequences.

**Here's an example code:**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, DateTime, Float, create_engine, Sequence
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'PERSONS'

    id_seq = Sequence('PERSONS_SEQ', metadata=Base.metadata)
    id = Column('ID', String(20), id_seq, primary_key=True)
    created_date = Column('CREATED_DATE', DateTime)

    def __init__(self, created_date):
        self.created_date

engine = create_engine("<some connection string trolololo>")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

created_at = datetime.strptime('2019-01-01 12:02:03', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
new_person = Person(
    created_date=created_at
)
session.add(new_account_payments)
session.flush()
session.commit()
```

**The errors/problems**

The initial problem is the sequence which is resulting in this error:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Instance <Person at 0x7f1d7fb2de48> has a NULL identity key.  If this is an auto-generated value, check that the database table allows generation of new primary key values, and that the mapped Column object is configured to expect these generated values.  Ensure also that this flush() is not occurring at an inappropriate time, such as within a load() event.
```

I have tried adding `autoincrement="auto"` but that just gave me different error suggesting it's only working with INTs and not STRINGs.

I did not manage to check if the date format is working yet due to aforementioned problem however I will update the thread once that is solved.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that you lack the `__init__` function. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30217587/6018688

Comment: Hey thanks for quick response. Using Declarative system you apparently don't have to provide the `__init__` function and updated the example code above. I have added it regardless as it is allowed according to the documentation. Unfortunately it did not help nor change the error.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#associating-a-sequence-with-the-metadata)

> While the above is a prominent idiomatic pattern, it is recommended that the Sequence in most cases be explicitly associated with the MetaData, using the Sequence.metadata parameter

So try adding the meta data and using the orm definition (shown in the docs)

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'PERSONS'


    id_seq = Sequence('PERSONS_SEQ', metadata=Base.metadata)
    id = Column(String(20), id_seq, server_default=id_seq.next_value(), primary_key=True)

    created_date = Column('CREATED_DATE', DateTime)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, that was a good lead however did not work for me - still the same behaviour. I have updated my example code to reflect your suggestions. You'll see that I skipped the `server_default` as it is officially not working with Oracle according to the documentation.

Comment: Not working for me too

Comment: doesn't work for Oracle  @guilhermecgs

Answer (score 0):

After long experimentation the above example minus the `__init__` function and `session.flush()` started to work. I might have overcomplicated the issue by experimenting with couple things at a time.

I still don't know how to force prefix on the `Sequence`. Please let me know if you do.